# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method in a JpaRepository

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use the technologies jpa, hibernate, spring boot - data, api REST.

I have the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'walletRestService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'walletRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'walletRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract java.lang.Long com.wj.dao.WalletRepository.createWallet(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)! No property createWallet found for type Wallet!

Here is my code :

Entity user:

```
package com.wj.entities;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id; 
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Wallet> wallets = new ArrayList<>();

public User() {
    super();
}

public User(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}



public User(Long id, String name) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}



public User(Long id, String name, List<Wallet> wallets) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.wallets = wallets;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<Wallet> getWallets() {
    return wallets;
}

public void setWallets(List<Wallet> wallets) {
    this.wallets = wallets;
}


}
```

Entity wallet:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String name;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
@JsonBackReference    
private User user;

public Wallet() {
    super();
}




public Wallet(String name, User user) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.user = user;
}




public Wallet(Long id, String name, User user) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.user = user;
}



public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}


}
```

restApi:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/wallets", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Wallet save(@RequestBody Wallet wallet) {
    User user = wallet.getUser();

    Long id = walletRepository.createWallet(user.getId(), wallet.getName());
    User boundUser = wallet.getUser();
    User simpleUser = new User(boundUser.getId(), boundUser.getName());
    wallet = new Wallet(id, wallet.getName(), simpleUser);
    return walletRepository.save(wallet);
}

DAO:  

package com.wj.dao;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.wj.entities.Wallet;

public interface WalletRepository extends JpaRepository<Wallet, Long>{
   Long createWallet(Long id, String name);
}
```

Comment: Show your implementation of WalletRepository.

Answer (score 7):

This declaration in your `WalletRepository`  interface is not valid for Spring :

```
Long createWallet(Long id, String name);
```

How do you want that Spring guesses what the `createWallet()` method is designed to create and persist a `Wallet` entity with a `Long id` and a `String name` ?

In fact the methods you declare in your `WalletRepository` interface are retrieval methods that rely on naming conventions to allow Spring create the queries for you.   And `create` is not referenced in the Spring Data documentation :

> [**4.4.2. Query Creation**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)
>
> The mechanism strips the prefixes `find…By`, `read…By`, `query…By`,
>   `count…By`, and `get…By` from the method and starts parsing the rest of
>   it.

As Spring didn't recognize `create`, it probably tries to resolve `createWallet` as a field of the entity.  Whereas the message :

> No property createWallet found for type Wallet!

To save an entity, instead use the method provided in the `JpaRepository` :

```
<S extends T> S save(S entity);
```

which for your repository will be inferred as :

```
Wallet save(Wallet entity);
```

And adapt your client code to create the `Wallet` instance and to pass it to `save()`.

Such as :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/wallets", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Wallet save(@RequestBody Wallet wallet) {
    User boundUser = wallet.getUser();
    return walletRepository.save(wallet);
}
```

Comment: I did not really understand your answer. Could you give me an example with my code? thank you

Comment: Trying to do as you told me, he shows me the following error:  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Collection has neither generic type or OneToMany.targetEntity() defined: com.wj.entities.User.wallets

Comment: You don't need to declare the method. It is already provided in the JpaRepository. But what is the goal of the createWallet() method ?

Comment: It allows me to create a wallet, knowing that a wallet has a user and name. When I call createWallet () in restService it forces me to create it in the DAO. Otherwise what function must I call in restService, to avoid making an error, knowing that to create a wallet I need to set the user.id and the name?