# UnsatisfiedDependencyException for customer method

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-repositories

I get an error after running spring boot in commandline following this: https://egkatzioura.com/2016/06/03/add-custom-functionality-to-a-spring-data-repository/

My project soruce code is on github: https://github.com/b3nhysteria/exprole_spring

The issue is on application :

```
System.out.println("============"+customerService.getListTransactionByCustomer());
```

The implementation in service is

```
public String getListTransactionByCustomer (){
    return customerRepository.getAllTransaction();
}
```

After adding a custom repo + implementation for method , even after change just to return message, I still got problem.

If anyone have same suggestion, i'll try it

BTW, this script is for exploring / studying.

Comment: How does your spring-boot configuration look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `CustomerRepository` you extend `TransactionRepoCustom`

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, CustomerId>, TransactionRepoCustom {
    // ...
}
```

So, Spring tries to find an implementation of method [`public String getAllTransaction()`](https://github.com/b3nhysteria/exprole_spring/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cart/repository/TransactionRepoCustom.java#L13) declared in `TransactionRepoCustom` (and fails to do so).

To fix this you need to either:

- Implement `getAllTransaction`; maybe create another class `TransactionRepoCustomImpl` (recommended!), or
- Declare a default implementation for `getAllTransaction` in the interface (if you use Java 8).

---

Following the first approach it would be something like:

```
public class TransactionRepoCustomImpl implements TransactionRepoCustom {
    @Override
    public String getAllTransaction() {
        return "logic for your custom implementation here";
    }
}
```

Following the last approach it would be:

```
public interface TransactionRepoCustom {
    public default String getAllTransaction() {
        return "Not implemented yet!"; // of course, this is just a naive implementation to state my point
    }
}
```

---

**Additional notes:**

This happens becase Spring uses behind scenes default (method) implementations for `CustomerRepository` provided by the interfaces it `implements`. For example, this is the case with `Jparepository` interface: you are able to use [`customerRepository.findAll()`](https://github.com/b3nhysteria/exprole_spring/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cart/service/CustomerServices.java#L37), and you didn't declare (nor implemented) that method in `CustomerRepository` (it was taken from an implementation of `Jparepository`, packed for you in a dependency, most probably).

Now, when you create your own interface (`TransactionRepoCustom`) and implemented it by `CustomerRepository`, Spring tries to find an implementation of all the methods declared in `TransactionRepoCustom`. As you didn't provide any, spring fails to create that bean for you.

In this case with the fix I provided Spring finds an implementation of that method, so it can create the bean for you.

Lastly, I said the recommended would be to provide an implementation for that method because the way to do things in Spring is declare the methods in an interface and provide their implementations in other classes (default implementations for that interface). In this case you can create a separate class for that or implement the `getAllTransaction` method in `CustomerRepository`.

When there is only one method (arguable) it could be fine to declare a `default` implementation in the same interface, but if the interface grows then it could be hard to maintain.

Comment: wow it's work.. but i dont quite understand behind it, why i have to add default keyword in my interface? so how about if i want add another method in TransactionRepoCustom interface? and how about the recommendation?

Comment: @Benikurniawan see the section **Additional notes** I just added to the answer. I hope I explained as detailed as possible and didn't left anything out :)

Comment: nice i get it, but how about if i need some custom method? like getAllTransaction ? if i put it in CustomerRepository, how can i implements the body? so sorry for my lack knowledge

Comment: @Benikurniawan my bad, you cannot implement that method in `CustomerRepository` (not without using the `default` mechanism mentioned in the post, it's an interface!) you need to create another class which implements `TransactionRepoCustom`... there you implement your logic for `getAllTransaction`. Sorry for this detail I missed :(.... I updated the post

Comment: i just try to follow from your recommendation but still got error, i push it in master branch i hope you / anybody can help me

Comment: @Benikurniawan, The new issue you are having is because of the invalid method name `getAllTransaction`.... see this and you'll understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51115098/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-create-query-method-in-a-jpareposi  ... let me know if you finally manage to solve it... if you think it's getting to complicated for you, post another question here on SO with the full log it's generated in the console.... BTW, this is a separate issue from the one you asked in the original question.... that's why I recommend you to post another question

Comment: @Benikurniawan in just a few words.... the methods you create in the interfaces repositories must be meaningful to JPA in order to let it know what query it should create for you for that method... the key in the log is this part: `Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.String com.cart.repository.TransactionRepoCustom.getAllTransaction()!` **`No property getAllTransaction found for type Customer!`**

Comment: BTW, what are you trying to get with this method: `getAllTransaction`?

Comment: i want to create method for get all transaction with customer data, so in my mind, i want to create hashmap with contain data customer + list of order detail in that method, or it's not the best solution in spring or logic or etc? any suggestion for help me better, i would be appreciate it, btw i follow your recommendation in no 1, but still got error bean name